# Ms Teams Bot Icon is not displayed

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I've used app studio from MS Teams to creat a manifest for a Bot App. I've uploaded the full color picture as well as trasparent outlone. However the icon is not displaying at the chat window.  Only the default icon is visivle.

Any ideas, how can I solve the issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the icon conform to these guidelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-package#icons ?  icon: .png 192x192 pixels and outline: 32x32 pixels with only white and transparent

Comment: @EricDahlvang yes, the icone was created according to the guidelines. Anyways I left this to check later, when I reload MS Teams today everything worked and the icon was there. Still note sure what was the issue thought...

Comment: Good to hear you've got it working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your bot sideloaded or uploaded to your organization's private app store? In those cases, the image used for the bot in the chat window is taken from the bot registration in Bot Framework. (This is a known issue that we're tracking.)

To change your bot's icon:

- If you registered your bot using App Studio:

  1. Go to https://dev.botframework.com/bots and sign in with the same account you use in Teams
  2. Select your bot, then go to Settings
  3. Click on "Upload custom icon"
- If you registered your app using the Azure portal:

  1. Go to the Bot Service or Bot Channels Registration resource in Azure
  2. Go to Settings
  3. Upload a custom icon

Comment: thanks a lot Adrian. I've done earlier everything, what you described, but the issue was still there, so I decided to come back to it later. Todays after reopen Ms Teams and checking it onces again, everything worked. Not sure what was the issue, but thanks anyways.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Teams caches the bot icon for some time (I believe 24h), so it will take some time to show up in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

As @Adrian Solis answer is indeed correct, I just wanted to add that it can also be related to caching issues. If you are changing icons and want to check if everything is working as expected, you can delete your browsers cache or the cache of the Microsoft Teams Windows App.

The Microsoft Teams Windows App has the [following cache folders](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9e1c12b-47a6-4b12-8d5c-a57fda4d9042/what-folders-are-used-by-teams-for-caching). Just stop the app, delete everything in this folders and start it again.

- %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\application cache\cache\
- %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\blob_storage\
- %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\Cache\
- %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\databases\
- %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\GPUcache\
- %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\IndexedDB\
- %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\Local Storage\
- %appdata%\Microsoft\teams\tmp\